# Ember 2, Modals as a Service (without elsewhere, wormhole and anything else)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, ember-data, bootstrap-modal

I need few simply modals in my Ember 2 project.

I tried "https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog" and other few libraries. But I'm unhappy.

I tried with this: https://ember-twiddle.com/5abf3206528997900de17939fd768f54

What do you suggest? Wher I'm failing?

Anyway I have a problem: **how to activate willDestroy() and willRender() of every component and sub-component?**

Comment: ember-modal-dialog needs sass. Are your sass configurations ok?

Comment: The question is not about "ember-modal-dialog".

Comment: `willDestroy` and `willRender` is placed in `actions` hash in your twiddle. They are not actions but hooks. So define them as function.

Comment: your code works for me. Whats your problem? And why are you unhappy with the libraries? Maybe you could describe what exactly you want? How should your modal work?